# node server.js won't work

Tags: node.js, angular, heroku, npm

In my application I use :

- "node": "7.2.1",
- "npm": "4.4.4"
- "@angular/cli": "1.4.9",
- "@angular/core": "4.4.6"

I deploy my application in heroku, it build but when I run it, it show "Application error" when I check the heroku logs it shows

```
2018-03-05T18:09:46.391200+00:00 app[web.1]: - npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2018-03-05T18:09:46.391279+00:00 app[web.1]: - npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2018-03-05T18_09_46_383Z-debug.log
```

Where can I find those .log files ?

When I run "node server.js" it's still waiting without doing or showing any thing

here is my server.js file

```
    // server.js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const path = require('path');

// Run the app by serving the static files
// in the dist directory
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/dist'));
// Start the app by listening on the default
// Heroku port
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080);

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", '*');
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", true);
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS');
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", 'Origin,X-Requested-With,Content-Type,Accept,content-type,application/json');
  next();
});
app.get('/*', function (req, res) {

  var origin = req.get('origin');
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/dist/index.html'));
});
```

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The path to your log files are outputted here:

```
2018-03-05T18:09:46.391279+00:00 app[web.1]: - npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2018-03-05T18_09_46_383Z-debug.log
```

To see the entire log file run this command:

```
cat /app/.npm/_logs/2018-03-05T18_09_46_383Z-debug.log
```

Hopefully that will help you find the issue.
Also, make sure to run
     `ng build`
 before trying to serve the compiled output.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that doesn't work , do you have any idea why "npm start" still blocked and doesn't do or show anything until I closed it ?